# using image in .md file from the same folder in Next.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I am working on a blog using Next.js Static Site Generator. We have a blog folder that contains other folders of individual blogs. Each blog contains some images and a `.md` file. The `.md` file is using images to display. The images are not showing. If I add images to `public` folder it works. But is there any way I can use images from the same folder itself.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to follow the Next.js rules,
Store the static images in public folder. Thats what Next.js is generated for.
Access to images besides images in public folder wouldnt be automatic.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving